# Problem storing prepared statement result into json array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I wanted to store results from prepared statement into an array and then convert into an json. But i am not getting the required format of json i want.

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("select course_id,course_name from mas_course");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($courseid, $coursename); 
$cnt = $stmt->num_rows;

$myObj = array();

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $myObj['courseid'][] = $courseid;
        $myObj['coursename'][] = $coursename;
    }

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
    echo $myJSON;
```

its giving me output like

```
{
"id": ["123", "345"],
"name": ["abc", "xyz"]
}
```

But i want

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "abc"
},
{
    "id": "345",
    "name": "xyz"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the json in the desired format each row from the database needs to be an entry in the output json - create an array and add to it in the loop

```
$output=[];
while( $stmt->fetch() ) $output[]=(object)array(
    'id'    =>  $courseid,
    'name'  =>  $coursename
);
$json=json_encode( $output );
```

Comment: thanks :) i was thinking of foreach loop, but i think it will not work here, or work ?

Answer (score 2):

Your adding to the result in the wrong order, but as you only fetch the columns you want you can shorten this to use [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), which will fetch all the data without the need of a loop...

```
$output = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode( $output );
```

If you want the columns to have a different name in the array, use an alias in the SQL to set the name.

Comment: short and sweet!